# Cannot retrieve data between two time ranges in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to display all records from the table where the user entered start time and 
end time lies between the database column start_time and end_time. I have used between but it is not giving proper results.Rows are fetched only if my start_time or end_time matches the database values. For eg. only if i enter 07:00:00 or 21:00:00 in start time field or end time field respectively.

> Database Structure :

```
id              int(11) Autoincrement
start_time  datetime NULL    
end_time    datetime NULL
```

> Database Data:

```
Start_time                end_time
2019-07-04 07:00:00 2019-07-04 21:00:00
```

> SQL Query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM `hours`
WHERE TIME(start_time) BETWEEN "07:15:00" and "20:00:00"
AND TIME(end_time) BETWEEN "07:15:00" and "20:00:00"
```

> Codeigniter Query is:

```
$this->db->where('TIME(start_time) BETWEEN "'. date('H:i:s',strtotime($start_time)). '" and "'. date('H:i:s',strtotime($end_time)).'"');
$this->db->where('TIME(end_time) BETWEEN "'. date('H:i:s',strtotime($start_time)). '" and "'. date('H:i:s',strtotime($end_time)).'"');
```

link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/958b05/6

Comment: Shouldn't your `TIME(start_time) BETWEEN "07:15:00" and "20:00:00"` is at or before the db start _time? I mean, wasn't it suppose to be something like this `TIME(start_time) BETWEEN "07:00:00" and "20:00:00"` or `TIME(start_time) BETWEEN "06:15:00" and "20:00:00"`?

Comment: @tcadidot0: The database time will be 07:00:00 for start and 21:00:00 for end, i have textfield where user will enter his start time and end time if his time range fall between database time range in this case suppose i enter 13:00:00 and 18:15:00 then the record will be fetched but in the above scenario i only get rows when i enter 07:00:00 in start field or 09:00:00 in the end field.

Comment: Ok, in you database data example, your start_time=07:00:00 and your end_time=21:00:00.. with these data, do you get any result when running your sql query?

Comment: I only get result when i enter range from "07:00:00" and "21:00:00" but if i enter 10:00:00 - 18:00:00 or any other values which lies in between the range the result is empty.

Comment: Please try here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/958b05/2 . If you make changes, make sure in the link, the last number is changed to other number and copy the link into your question. Thanks

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/958b05/6 why this is not returning rows as it fullfills search criteria.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you want is when a user input start time 10:00:00 and end time 18:00:00 - and it's in between range of the `start_time` and `end_time`, it should return a value, is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196241/discussion-between-user3653474-and-tcadidot0).

Comment: yes exactly same thing i want

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this method:

```
SELECT *
FROM `hours`
WHERE 36000 >= TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(start_time))
AND 64800 <= TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(end_time));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/958b05/12

I've changed the time value into seconds because I had error in the fiddle. The original query look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `hours`
WHERE "10:00:00" >= TIME(start_time)
AND "18:00:00" <= TIME(end_time);
```

So "10:00:00" is start time and "18:00:00" is end time by user input, and use that to lookup into the start_time and end_time value. If the user inputs are the same or in between start_time and end_time, it will return a value.